How to periodically run a function with express on vercel
I have a simple express app running locally and I want to run a function every 10 seconds.
...
fetchData();
setTimeout(fetchData, 10000);

app.listen(PORT, async function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});



module.exports = app;

it works perfectly fine in development, but deploying it to vercel it just runs one single time. what do i need to configure? I checked the documentation but didnt find something regarding to this. Using a Cronjob is no option for me since i need to call the function every 5-10 seconds.
Thanks in advance

The real question is "why?". Things like periodic data fetches are generally a job for cron/a task scheduler, where you schedule a separate command/script/etc so that it  fetches data and puts it somewhere that the server can access, with the server simply being able to trust that when it access that data (through the filesystem, by using the same database, etc), that it will be provided with the most up to date data.

i can tell you why, cronjobs seems to be limited to 1minute, this is too long for my usecase

What are you doing that requires updates every 10 seconds, though?

Vercel provide that to call specific API using cron jobs
here's how https://vercel.com/blog/cron-jobs
NOTE, Vercel deal with NodeJS apps as a serverless endpoints, this means your server is in a sleep mode till it get called.
so it will never make a cron jobs alive as its not a running process.
so its impossible to run smth like that even.
setTimeout() method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout
so If you want to run a job ever 10 sec you need to use setInterval(), but still this isn't going to work on Vercel.
I hope that I cleared that to you.

thank you very much for the explanation why its prop not working. looking into the vercel docs i cant use it since the minimum they offer is every minute, this is too slow. any ideas on that?

i guess packages like node-cron dont work either?

Nothing will work on Vercel, you can have a cron worker on cloudflare, this will fix the issue for you. add what logic you want externally and if you need some data from your server, just provide them using an API
